# Link broken but when "ls" is used on link in terminal the content is displayed

Tags: bash, symbolic-link

I noticed an interesting fact today. I have a link on my Desktop pointing to windows partition (dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 & Win8.1). Because this partition is not automatically mounted the link is marked broken at restart. When I mount the partition and than double click on it it gives me an error that is broken too. But if I use `ls` command in Terminal on the link I can see all the content. Why is the behaviour different?

Of course if `ls` is used on the link before the partition is mounted, the content isn't shown.

Comment: ls doesnt force mount.

Comment: @j0h Sorry but I still don't understand. Can you provide more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart desktop manager, `nautilus`.

1. Kill all its processes

   ```
   sudo killall nautilus
   ```
2. Start it over if it did't (it can be started by just opening a folder)

   ```
   nautilus -n & disown
   ```